# .NET 3.5 Client Framework redistributable?

Tags: .net, deployment

It's nice from Microsoft to offer things like the Client Framework for anybody who doesn't need the complete framework to run an application.
But for about an hour I a searching the web for a redistributable version of this package.
I can't find anything.

It looks like Client Framework is only possible for Click-Once deployment or a bootstrapper who will download the framework. These are no options for me.

On this page

```
http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?familyid=992cffcb-f8ce-41d9-8bd6-31f3e216285c&displaylang=en
```

I found a package that will contain both

```
"The download package contains the .NET Framework Client Profile and the full .NET Framework 3.5 Service Pack 1."
```

But again this is not what I need and it's even bigger that the singleFramework.

Is there anything like the .NET 3.5 Client Framework redistributable ?

Comment: http://smallestdotnet.com is quite handy and does give a link to an offline installer (http://download.microsoft.com/download/2/0/e/20e90413-712f-438c-988e-fdaa79a8ac3d/dotnetfx35.exe), but I suspect its the same as cedrou's answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no *official* Redistributable version for v3.5. I've been searching for one myself but I've given up.

The only possibility is, some knowledgeable person identified where the web-installer downloaded the files, put them together in a nice package and uploaded it somewhere.

Of course, if Google can't give you the answer to THAT package, its highly unlikely that you'll find one.

Answer (score 2):

If you download the [full client package](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?familyid=992cffcb-f8ce-41d9-8bd6-31f3e216285c&displaylang=en) and open it with your favorite compression software (WinZIP, WinRAR, 7-zip, IZArc, ...), you'd be able to extract several setup files named:

- `DotNetFx20Client_Package_x86.exe (14 MiB)`
- `DotNetFx30Client_Package_x86.exe (8 MiB)`
- `DotNetFx35Client_Package_x86.exe (< 1MiB)`

It seems that they are cumulative installer for the 3 versions of client framework.

But I have no idea if you can redistribute these package directly, whithout the full package.

Comment: I just tried this on a VM with only .NET 2.0 installed. I just ran the 30 and 35 client package, and than ran an application that requires 3.5. It works, woohoo - 9/23 MB instead of 255 :D

Comment: Question: Why does it work? Shouldn't the full client profile be 39MB? :X

Comment: I think it's because the installer must use the full (not client) setup if there is already a full version of .NET which is installed.